# Rowcolors and tabularx: Colors not reset in each new table

Tags: color, tabularx

I'm having an issue with `rowcolors` from the `xcolor` package.

Whenever I use `rowcolors` before a table, it seems that the row counter does not reset with each `tabularx` environment.

I read that `rowcolors` uses the `rownum` counter internally, and I tried resetting this with `\global\rownum=1`, but unfortunately this does not seem to work.

I am basically just trying to alter all my tabularx environments to be colored:

```
\definecolor{table-shade}{gray}{0.9}
\let\oldtabularx\tabularx
\let\endoldtabularx\endtabularx
\renewenvironment{tabularx}{\table\rowcolors{1}{white}{table-shade}\oldtabularx}{\endoldtabularx\endtable}
```

I'd welcome any suggestions, and thanks for your help.

Comment: have you seen [Tables: Colouring odd/even mixed up](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58390) it sounds quite similar...

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example (MWE) that generates the problem you're trying to solve. E.g., from your current description, I can't tell if you have two (or more) `tabularx` environments inside a `table` environment.

Comment: There are multiple tabularx environments but no table environments.

Comment: Neither the xpreto or preto commands mentioned in the other post seem to work. Thanks for pointing out this option though.

Comment: Brian, once again, seconding Mico: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Because no new answer is possible, this works for me even without `etoolbox` or `xpatch` (linebreaks disappear in comments): `\usepackage[table]{xcolor} \definecolor{table-shade}{gray}{0.9} \usepackage{tabularx} \let\oldtabularx\tabularx \let\endoldtabularx\endtabularx \renewenvironment{tabularx}{\rowcolors{1}{white}{table-shade}\oldtabularx}{\endoldtabularx}`.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I just declared my own counter and used rowcolor or cellcolor with an if statement to achieve the desired results. I then reset my counter after each tabularx environment.