# Pandoc Markdown Table header background Color

Tags: tables, backgrounds, pandoc

I am using pandoc markdown to convert my documents to pdf. I have tables in the document that required formatting. I was able to create alternative colors for rows. However, I am unable to change the background color of the table heading. I believe pandoc using longtable and booktabs in the background. Is there any style or hooks that I can created in order to get this resolved? I tried with pandoc-filters and I could not succeed as the filter crashed on me.

I tried to create a .tex file out of the markdown and apparently I am unable to get that working.

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.[image]

**Edit** (10/11/2017)

Adding More details:

```
\subsection{Definitions, Acronyms and
Abbreviations}\label{definitions-acronyms-and-abbreviations}

\begin{longtable}[]{@{}lll@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{\#} & \textbf{Acronym} & \textbf{Definition}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
1 & App & Application\tabularnewline
2 & xxx & XXXXXX\tabularnewline
3 & yyy & YYYYYYYY\tabularnewline
4 & SDK & Software Development Kit\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
```

**Template**

```
%
% tables
%
$if(tables)$
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2} % table spacing
\usepackage{longtable}\rowcolors{3}{white!100}{feeblegrey!100}
\arrayrulecolor{white}


$endif$
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)]

Comment: Give us the markdown code and the command used to generate the latex code if you don't want / can't edit the latex file, or the relevant part of the latex file (but in a minimal document, so that we could copy-paste-compile it easily). Apparently, editing the template is an option? Phrased differently: do you want to edit the markdown file, the template, the latex file, the macro to go from markdown to latex, all of them, or something else ?

Comment: Thanks for your welcome! appreciate you keeping me up to date on the minimum mandates of the forum.

Comment: @Clément - Yes, I have an option to customize or edit the template.  I have shared it.  I have added them to the actual post as an edit.  I understand that Pandoc is limited in terms of customizations on the markdown.  However, it would be easy for me to take it on the template and make the customizations.  Also the alternate row color, I have achieved using the template.  It is the default template of Pandoc with little styles and coloring added here and there.

Comment: Does replacing `\rowcolors{3}{white!100}{feeblegrey!100}` with  `\rowcolors{1}{white!100}{feeblegrey!100}` in the template do what you want?

Comment: I tried doing the way you said along with the fix mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58390/tables-colouring-odd-even-mixed-up). Apparently, the code works only based on the stack exchange link.  But I am unable to get a different color for my table header.